# From origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

What I'm doing is, after choosing a file it calls an API. If it's a success (valid file) it gives me the total price. If it's a falsely formatted file, it gives me the relevant error from the backend.

Now, when I choose a correct file it works perfectly. But when I use a wrong file - it doesn't give me the error but it gives me following errors.

When I make the API call I get a CORS error saying :

POST https://test.test.test.com/subs/v12/2Subs net::ERR_ABORTED 422 (Unprocurable Entity)

> Access to fetch at 'https://test.test.test.com/subs/v12/2Subs' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

But I get this only when I upload a file with false format. When I use Moesif CORS everything works perfectly.

But when I do this without Moesif CORS I get above error only when I load an incorrect file.

I tried using `mode: "no-cors"` also, But it didn't help me to get rid of POST error I'm getting.

Token is coming to the page because I printed it at the page load and it printed.

Here is how API header looks like.

```
var res = fetch('https://test.test.test.com/subs/v12/2Subs', {
    method: "POST", // POST
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "no-cache",

    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem("userToken")

    },

    redirect: "follow",
    referrer: "no-referrer",
```

Comment: if origin is "null" that means your source of the request is from a page not served by http or https, correct? If so, then there is *nothing you can do about it* (at least not in Chrome) ... plus, stop putting response headers in requests ...`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header and has no place in a request

Comment: @JaromandaX Hey, But I'm making the request from a page served by https noh :/

Comment: Seems like an issue with how CORS is configured on the server you are trying to access.

Comment: are you? I've only ever seen *origin 'null' has been blocked* when the origin is not http/https (origin, not destination - there's no indication what the origin is served by from what you posted) - in the address bar, does it say "http://" or "https://" or "file:///"?

Comment: I guess you should have a proper validation for the object/data being posted in client side before sending it to server. This error might occur at times when we are posting incorrect data which couldn't be parsed as the object you expect in backend. I'm sure the request object which was received in backend method is null.

Comment: @JaromandaX - Hey it says https://

Comment: @Sivaprasath : Yeah- this is just to the initial release, the thing is backend send me a error when I send a incorrect file. It works perfectly with Moesif CORS enabled. Why can't I do it when I disable to CORS.

Comment: @Sandy95 when you send any of these two headers `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` or `'Authorization': <Auth token>`, the browser runs a pre-flight check before actual request. And the browser is expecting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response. Modern browsers only send original request when this header is present in pre-flight check. The chrome plugin that you are using most probably intercepts the response from server and adds this header. This is fine for dev but your application will not work for users as they are not using the plugin.

Comment: Therefor the server/api that you are trying to access needs to be edited and properly configured for CORS.

Comment: How weird, wonder why the origin is *null* then